# Unable to create objects in hbase shell

Tags: nosql, hbase, cloudera

When I am tryig to create namespace in hbase shell, I am getting below error:

ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PleaseHoldException: Master is initializing at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.checkInitialized(HMaster.java:2411) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.checkNamespaceManagerReady(HMaster.java:2416) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.createNamespace(HMaster.java:2581) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterRpcServices.createNamespace(MasterRpcServices.java:459) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.MasterProtos$MasterService$2.callBlockingMethod(MasterProtos.java:58766) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2191) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:112) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:183) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:163)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the status of hbase-master service "sudo service hbase-master status" its running fine.

Then I started hbase-region server sudo service hbase-regionserver start and it worked for me